# Search Android C# Xamarin Sqlite Database

Tags: c#, android, database, sqlite, search

I need some help to figure out how to search my SQLite database.
I am trying to search for their cake and stars; this is my connection:

```
// Create our connection
string folder = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
var db = new SQLiteConnection(System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, "OnTopFiles.db"));
db.CreateTable<User>();

// Insert note into the database
var note = new User { cake = "frosting marble", stars = "5" };
db.Insert(note);

// Show the automatically set ID and message.
Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", note.cake, note.stars);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a WHERE query:

```
var query = conn.Table<User>().Where(u => u.Cake.StartsWith("frosting"));
foreach (var user in query)
{
    // Use user.cake or other properties
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use SQL directly. The library you are using hides the SQLite SQL so most of the SQLite syntax is hidden from you. This library is pure .NET Standard and runs on all Xamarin Platforms. You have the full power of SQL so searching is the same as other platforms.

https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/SQLite.Net.Standard